# pandas group by year, rank by sales column, in a dataframe with duplicate data

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby, rank

I would like to create a rank on year (so in year 2012, Manager B is 1.  In 2011, Manager B is 1 again). I struggled with the pandas rank function for awhile and DO NOT want to resort to a for loop.

```
s = pd.DataFrame([['2012','A',3],['2012','B',8],['2011','A',20],['2011','B',30]], columns=['Year','Manager','Return'])

Out[1]:     
   Year Manager  Return    
0  2012       A       3    
1  2012       B       8    
2  2011       A      20    
3  2011       B      30
```

---

The issue I'm having is with the additional code (didn't think this would be relevant before):

```
s = pd.DataFrame([['2012', 'A', 3], ['2012', 'B', 8], ['2011', 'A', 20], ['2011', 'B', 30]], columns=['Year', 'Manager', 'Return'])
b = pd.DataFrame([['2012', 'A', 3], ['2012', 'B', 8], ['2011', 'A', 20], ['2011', 'B', 30]], columns=['Year', 'Manager', 'Return'])

s = s.append(b)
s['Rank'] = s.groupby(['Year'])['Return'].rank(ascending=False)

raise Exception('Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index '
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Any ideas?
This is the real data structure I am using.
Been having trouble re-indexing..

Comment: Why on earth did you do `s= s.append(b)`, appending a duplicate copy with the same indices? That just creates the problem. (and `append(..., ignore_index=False)` fixes it, as @unutbu said). But what was the need for duplicating the dataframe rows?

Answer (score 29):

It sounds like you want to group by the `Year`, then rank the `Returns` in descending order.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.DataFrame([['2012', 'A', 3], ['2012', 'B', 8], ['2011', 'A', 20], ['2011', 'B', 30]],
                 columns=['Year', 'Manager', 'Return'])
s['Rank'] = s.groupby(['Year'])['Return'].rank(ascending=False)
print(s)
```

yields

```
   Year Manager  Return  Rank
0  2012       A       3     2
1  2012       B       8     1
2  2011       A      20     2
3  2011       B      30     1
```

---

To address the OP's revised question: The error message

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

occurs when trying to `groupby/rank` on a DataFrame with duplicate values in the index. You can avoid the problem by constructing `s` to have unique index values after appending:

```
s = pd.DataFrame([['2012', 'A', 3], ['2012', 'B', 8], ['2011', 'A', 20], ['2011', 'B', 30]], columns=['Year', 'Manager', 'Return'])
b = pd.DataFrame([['2012', 'A', 3], ['2012', 'B', 8], ['2011', 'A', 20], ['2011', 'B', 30]], columns=['Year', 'Manager', 'Return'])
s = s.append(b, ignore_index=True)
```

yields

```
   Year Manager  Return
0  2012       A       3
1  2012       B       8
2  2011       A      20
3  2011       B      30
4  2012       A       3
5  2012       B       8
6  2011       A      20
7  2011       B      30
```

---

If you've already appended new rows using

```
s = s.append(b)
```

then use `reset_index` to create a unique index:

```
s = s.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: The issue i'm having is with the additional code (didnt think this would be relevant before):