# How to produce new index, ranking groups by variable?

Tags: pandas, insert, series, rank

Wondering what sort of group by I can use to produce this result.

Input:

```
    Root    Strike
33  AAL     49
43  AAL     49
44  AAL     49.5
35  AAL     50
45  AAL     50
```

Output

```
    Strike Num  Root    Strike
33  1           AAL     49
43  1           AAL     49
44  2           AAL     49.5
35  3           AAL     50
45  3           AAL     50
```

Comment: You want to create a new column 'Strike Num' ranking rows by Strike

Comment: In fact it's a duplicate of [python pandas rank by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604665/python-pandas-rank-by-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a group-by.
You want to create a new column 'Strike Num' ranking rows by Strike.
[pandas rank()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) automatically does the grouping, ordering, and gives you control over how ties are indexed; here you want the rank to be the smallest: `method='min'`

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), index_col=0, sep='\s+')

df.insert(0, 'Strike Num', df.Strike.rank(method='min').astype(int))

    Strike Num Root  Strike
33           1  AAL    49.0
43           1  AAL    49.0
44           3  AAL    49.5
35           4  AAL    50.0
45           4  AAL    50.0
```

Comment: Close, but instead using rank(mehtod='dense') gets the result I want. Thanks